# paste an image onto section of an image in a way it will expand inside the given area

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, animation

for now i have created an interface with two large labels using pyqt5 and i have used those labels to show images in order to get animation like illustration to my project. bellow images shows the pyqt interface holding the two images in two labels.

[image]

what i want to do now is to save these instances as images and later create an animation using them as frames. for now i have am using the same function to create other the images. the two images are made different due to the given input list of puzzle pieces. the size of the second image is large due to the expanding features of the pyqt.

following code is the function i used to create the images. it might not make complete sense. but its not that important for this question.

```
def make_img(results, puzzle):
    final = Image.new('RGBA', (165 * COL_NUM, 165 * ROW_NUM))
    # border = 100
    keys = list(results.keys())

            for i in keys:
        piece = puzzle[results[i]]
        image = piece.img
        corners = piece.corners
        pos = piece.pos
        # print("shape :",np.asarray(image).shape)
        w = np.asarray(image).shape[0]
        image = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
        cv2.putText(image, str(results[i]), (int(w / 2), int(w / 2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        image[np.all(image == [0, 0, 0, 255], axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        corner0 = corners[0]
        x = pos[0] - corner0[0]
        y = pos[1] - corner0[1]
        img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image))
        final.paste(img, (x, y), img)

    imageBox = final.getbbox()
    cropped = final.crop(imageBox)
    return cropped
```

i want to save a final frame by putting together both of these parts of them images.

is there a way to create a large empty image. and past those two part (maybe will have some other parts too) in to predefined section with expiation and centering features to it.

[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but have a look at TIFF as a format. It can save multiple images and layers within a single file. For example, in Photoshop you can save your work as a layered TIFF and when you open it, all your working layers are intact.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, what i want is not to save the image. i want to paste several images together to make a one large image. but i want to pasting to be in a predefined section of the new image with centering and expanding feature.. meaning the pasting part will expand and center inside the give region